# Meteor: unable to customize marker of google map

Tags: meteor, google-maps-markers

I am working on project using meteor(0.8.2). In this project, I have used google maps api. The default markers of the map are working properly but when i try to replace them with a "image.png" then the image icon is not visible on map. Any idea on this?

My code:

```
for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
      url: 'markerimage.png',// image is in root directory of meteor project.
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      title: place.name,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your image in a directory named "public" at the root of your project.

Then reference your image using "/markerimage.png"

Every file put in the public folder is served as a static asset to the client, see the docs for more info.